# Как в пакете flag работать с русским?

Tags: golang, кириллица

Подключаю пакет flag для парсинга аргументов командной строки следующим образом:

```
site := flag.String("site", "google.com", "Site address searching for in search results")
keyword := flag.String("key", "google.com", "Keyword searching for in SE")
flag.Parse()
```

Проблема возникает, если в параметр **key** передать строку на русском.
**flag** её просто не видит и в **keyword** всегда записывает "google.com".
Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот простой пример и он прекрасно работает

```
func main() {
    keyword := flag.String("key", "Ничего", "Что-то на русском")
    flag.Parse()

    if *keyword == "Ура" {
        fmt.Printf("%s - работает!", *keyword)
    }
}
```